# How to replicate Who bot people search criteria?

Tags: botframework, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-teams

Need help in implementing people/user search in the entire organization with a fuzzy search

Microsoft Graph API
People Search
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/people/?$search="Mary"
Perform a fuzzy search but this is done only on people collection of the signed-in user
Which doesn't give a result based on the entire organization

Users Search

```
Doesn't support following ODATA Parameters
1.$Search https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$search="Mary" is not supported
2.$filter doesn't support $filter=substring(displayName, 1) eq 'abc, xyz'
3.contains is also not supported $filter=contains(CompanyName,'Alfreds')
```

Comment: If the answer helpful you could accept it, to help the community. You can click check box beside your question to accept it.

Answer (score 2):

Seems your are trying to search user among your organization. But the way you tried is not supported.

If you want to search organization user you could try in following way

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$filter=startswith(displayName,'Kiron')
```

It will show all the name start with given value. See the screen shot

[image]

Please refer to this [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters#filter-parameter)